# Flickering in cordova page transtion

Tags: cordova

How to avoid the blank screen appearing when the page transition from one page to another thats is written in javascript function window.location="reguired page.html" for both android and ios.

After using **android:hardwareAccelerated="false** in android, the page transition flickering problem is not coming.

What is the **equivalent usage in iOS** instead of of this. In iOS which is used to solve this?

I am not using jquery mobile. How i am avoid this? Please help to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Use a single page architecture where resources are loaded as needed via XHR/Ajax.

Comment: i can't use single page, give any other solutions.

Comment: Why can't you use SPA? It's the best option to eliminate flicker between page loads. Plus your users will thank you for a more performant app.

Comment: we have crossed  half part of our app, and the design also very huge.so only have not used SPA. In android using  android:hardwareAccelerated="true", the issue is solved. But for iOS what will do?

Comment: Pretty sure there are no good options. I suppose you could write a plugin that throws up a loading screen that covers the entire webview as it loads, but that would still not be a smooth transition in any shape or form. You could try and get really fancy and snapshot the webview, throw that up in a native view, animate the view out as the page loaded and then animate the new webview in, but again -- hacky and will take a lot of work to get right. When people ask how they should architect their apps, we use SPA for a reason -- MPAs are far too problematic.